# Why am I having trouble comparing lines from input in Perl?

Tags: perl, validation, user-input

I don't know what I could be doing wrong with this simple transaction, but it's not working:

```
print "OK? (y or n)\n";
$ans = <>;
print "\n";
if($ans eq "y"){print $ans;}
```

I basically want to know how to test the user input.  This little bit of code won't work for me.  I'm just trying to print `$ans` if `y` is entered by the user.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: - I have also tried single quotes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're doing a couple things wrong.

(1) Don't use the diamond operator (<>) when you want <STDIN>. The diamond operator will also read files from @ARGV, which you probably don't want.

(2) $ans will never be equal to "y" unless you chomp it first. It will have a newline at the end.

Comment: thank you, why the eff does it tag on a \n? because i hit enter to register my answer? it should auto-chomp if you ask me...

Comment: You have the "why" correct. I'm sure there is something in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html that will allow auto-chomping or something.

Comment: No, Perl will not autochomp, though Cheese is right it should in most cases. I think Perl 6 does autochomp by default.

Comment: You do *not* want to autochomp if you have to tell the difference between reading a line terminated with \n vs. a partial line ending because of EOF (line ending because of EOF may signal a user abort or a partially flushed file.)

Comment: You can tell Perl to autochomp by specifying "#!/usr/bin/perl -l" on the first line. But the effect is global, so only do this if your script is tiny.

Comment: j_random_hacker: -l's autochomping only applies to the implicit readline created by -n or -p, not to any other readline, so it's not a global effect you need to be wary of.

Answer (score 5):

A cure-all for variables of mysterious content:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; # show newlines, tabs, etc in visible form
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print '$ans is really: ', Dumper($ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your direct question has been answered, you may want to look at alternatives like [Term::Readline](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Readline)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
if($ans eq 'y'){print $ans;}
```

?