# Perl Why doesn't POST work when the variable is set by <> rather than directly assigned?

Tags: perl, post

When I directly assign a name to the variable $connection_name, this script works, but I would like to take a user input and assign that to the variable.  When I do that, it doesn't work.  I get an error 400 bad request.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = "XXXX"

# Get name for connection
print "Connection Name?";
my $connection_name= <>;
print $connection_name;

# HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');

# POST data in the HTTP request body
my $post_data = "{
    \"name\":\"$connection_name\",
    \"origin_country\":\"us\",
    \"datasource_type\":\"cfdcb449-1204-44ba-baa6-9a8a878e6aa7\"
}"
$req->content($post_data);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I having trouble comparing lines from input in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608254/why-am-i-having-trouble-comparing-lines-from-input-in-perl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you hardcoded `$connection_name`, you probably didn't include a line feed as you do now. Add

```
chomp($connection_name);
```

And please use a proper JSON generator.

```
use JSON::XS qw( encode_json );

my $post_data = encode_json({
   name            => $connection_name,
   origin_country  => "us",
   datasource_type => "cfdcb449-1204-44ba-baa6-9a8a878e6aa7",
});
```